# Report ID: webapi-560e30f44811c; Message: Class name does not exis in Magento2

Tags: php-5.4, rest-api, magento2-dev-beta

I have created rest api it's not working Could you please suggest me where i went wrong?

> Error: main.CRITICAL: exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Report ID: webapi-560e33c7e2c45; Message: Class name does not exist'

my code is:

**app/etc/config.php**

```
modules' => 
  array (  
    'Learning_Test' => 1,
  ),
```

**app/code/Learning/Test/Api**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Test\Api;

interface WebserviceInterface
{

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function say($name);
}
```

**app/code/Learning/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Learning\Test\Api\WebserviceInterface" type="Learning\Test\Model\Webservice" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Learning/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">

    <!-- Example: curl http://192.168.0.52/magento-2/index.php/rest/V1/webservice/say/magento2 -->
    <route url="/V1/webservice/say/:name" method="GET">
        <service class="Learning\Test\Api\WebserviceInterface" method="say"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>

</routes>
```

**app/code/Learning/Test/Model/Webservice.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\Test\Model;
use Learning\Test\Api\WebserviceInterface;

class Webservice implements WebserviceInterface
{

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return string
     */
    public function say($name) {
        return ' Welcome to ' . $name;
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: your file name is `app/code/Learning/Test/Model/Webservice.php` but your class name is `VLC\Test\Model\Webservice`. is this a typo in the post , or this is the actual issue?

Comment: @Marius, it's Typing mistake now I have updated.

Comment: @Marius, please look my answer and confirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have achieved by adding below code in `WebserviceInterface.php`

```
/**
     * @param string $name of the param.
     * @return mixed|string of the param Value.
     */

    public function say($name);
```

I'm observing that when i have added above function with comments then it's working fine otherwise it's not working.

I don't know the comment is the key for the function to work?

If some one knows please let me know?

Comment: It must add type of value **"int|string"** ...

Answer (score 1):

Interface class is used to filter incoming and outgoing values. Based on phpdoc magento will prepare values to get from the request and pass to the model that handles it. Also response will also be filtered based on the phpdoc.